# How to maintain LINQ deferred execution?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, deferred-execution

Suppose I have an `IQueryable<T>` expression that I'd like to encapsulate the definition of, store it and reuse it or embed it in a larger query later.  For example:

```
IQueryable<Foo> myQuery =
    from foo in blah.Foos
    where foo.Bar == bar
    select foo;
```

Now I believe that I can just keep that myQuery object around and use it like I described.  But some things I'm not sure about:

1. **How best to parameterize it?** Initially I've defined this in a method and then returned the `IQueryable<T>` as the result of the method.  This way I can define `blah` and `bar` as method arguments and I guess it just creates a new `IQueryable<T>` each time.  Is this the best way to encapsulate the logic of an `IQueryable<T>`? Are there other ways?
2. **What if my query resolves to a scalar rather than `IQueryable`?**  For instance, what if I want this query to be exactly as shown but append `.Any()` to just let me know if there were any results that matched?  If I add the `(...).Any()` then the result is `bool` and immediately executed, right? Is there a way to utilize these `Queryable` operators (`Any`, `SindleOrDefault`, etc.) without immediately executing?  How does LINQ-to-SQL handle this?

**Edit:** Part 2 is really more about trying to understand what are the limitation differences between `IQueryable<T>.Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)` vs. `IQueryable<T>.Any(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)`. It seems as though the latter isn't as flexible when creating larger queries where the execution is to be delayed.  The `Where()` can be appended and then other constructs can be later appended and then finally executed.  Since the `Any()` returns a scalar value it sounds like it will immediately execute before the rest of the query can be built.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You have to be really careful about passing around IQueryables when you're using a DataContext, because once the context get's disposed you won't be able to execute on that IQueryable anymore.  If you're not using a context then you might be ok, but be aware of that.
2. .Any() and .FirstOrDefault() are **not** deferred.  When you call them they **will** cause execution to occur.  However, this may not do what you think it does.  For instance, in LINQ to SQL if you perform an .Any() on an IQueryable it acts as a IF EXISTS( SQL HERE ) basically.

You can chain IQueryable's along like this if you want to:

```
var firstQuery = from f in context.Foos
                    where f.Bar == bar
                    select f;

var secondQuery = from f in firstQuery
                    where f.Bar == anotherBar
                    orderby f.SomeDate
                    select f;

if (secondQuery.Any())  //immediately executes IF EXISTS( second query in SQL )
{
    //causes execution on second query 
    //and allows you to enumerate through the results
    foreach (var foo in secondQuery)  
    {
        //do something
    }

    //or

    //immediately executes second query in SQL with a TOP 1 
    //or something like that
    var foo = secondQuery.FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

Comment: It sounds like in #1, having a method that essentially constructs a new `IQueryable` each time is a *good thing* since this way I won't run into issues with disposal.  In #2, I'm confused how LINQ-to-SQL can translate the `Any` operator, yet I cannot defer.  If I were to use an `Any` operator within a larger query is it immediately executed there as well, or is it part of the larger query execution?

Comment: OK I think I'm almost there. If I were to embed an `.Any()` into a `where` clause then it wouldn't execute that in a loop, correct? It would compile to the appropriate SQL expression and send that down. So in effect, it isn't `.Any()` that prevents deferred execution as it is how it is being used. Basically if the result of a *whole* query is a scalar then the compiler figures you need the result now rather than continuing with building up an `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @McKAMEY correct, as soon as you use .Any() in a context that is not deferrable then it will execute.  In the case of .Where() it's looking for an expression, which is deferrable, so you're ok.  In the case of var or the foreach loop, those cause execution becuase they are not deferrable.

Answer (score 2):

A much better option than caching IQueryable objects is to cache Expression trees. All IQueryable objects have a property called Expression (I believe), which represents the current expression tree for that query.

At a later point in time, you can recreate the query by calling queryable.Provider.CreateQuery(expression), or directly on whatever the provider is (in your case a Linq2Sql Data Context).

Parameterizing these expression trees is slightly harder however, as they use ConstantExpressions to build in a value. In order to parameterize these queries, you WILL have to rebuild the query every time you want different parameters.

Comment: I would say that parameterizing (or more importantly encapsulating a single unit of logic) is the real goal here rather than caching. Considering that the C# compiler has already converted it, I don't think that a runtime equivalent would be of much use / performance benefit (as is what caching implies).

Comment: Can you explain why this option is better? As far as I understand you just unwrap the `Expression` to rewrap it later: why not keeping the wrapper as is?

Answer (score 2):

`Any()` used this way is deferred.

```
var q = dc.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Any());
```

`Any()` used this way is not deferred, but is still translated to SQL (the whole customers table is not loaded into memory).

```
bool result = dc.Customers.Any();
```

If you want a deferred Any(), do it this way:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
  public static Func<bool> DeferredAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
  {
    return () => source.Any();
  }
}
```

Which is called like this:

```
Func<bool> f = dc.Customers.DeferredAny();
bool result = f();
```

The downside is that this technique won't allow for sub-querying.

Comment: When you say deferred, it sounds like you mean I can define a lambda expression (or delegate) but not immediately execute it.  I think there is a subtlety to LINQ's concept of "deferred execution" which allows the operation to become part of a larger expression tree, which can be interpreted by the provider however it wants.

My question is more trying to get at what are the limitation differences between `IQueryable<T>.Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)` vs. `IQueryable<T>.Any(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)` as it seems as though the latter isn't as flexible.

Comment: That inflexibility comes from the difference in return types.  The type named 'bool' can have no deferred behavior.

Comment: this suggestion seems thread-unsafe to me (consider the DataContext)

Comment: @cottsak - all extension methods (including the ones for linq) are static, such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx  . static methods are threadsafe as long as there is no static state (such as a static property or field).

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial application of your query inside an expression

```
Func[Bar,IQueryable[Blah],IQueryable[Foo]] queryMaker = 
(criteria, queryable) => from foo in queryable.Foos
        where foo.Bar == criteria
        select foo;
```

and then you can use it by ...

```
IQueryable[Blah] blah = context.Blah;
Bar someCriteria = new Bar();
IQueryable[Foo] someFoosQuery = queryMaker(blah, someCriteria);
```

The query could be encapsulated within a class if you want to make it more portable / reusable.

```
public class FooBarQuery
{
  public Bar Criteria { get; set; }

  public IQueryable[Foo] GetQuery( IQueryable[Blah] queryable )
  {
     return from foo in queryable.Foos
        where foo.Bar == Criteria
        select foo;
  } 
}
```