# Linq2Sql datacontext login/logout behavior

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I am using L2S to check if a key already exists, and if it doesnt, create and insert one.  This same DataContext is also used to execute other queries within the same C# method.  I am implimenting the `using` keyword to dispose the DataContext after I am done with it.  I hooked up sql profiler and saw that it would Login, execute the query, then logout.  It seems to do this even if the same DataContext will perform a query or update later.  I thought the datacontext only logged in once, and performed all the queries during that one session?  Does how often you call SubmitChanges() matter?  Or what am i missing?

mock of what i am seeing:

```
using(Datacontext)
{
      //Audit Login
      var b = DataContext.Table.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Id == 4);
      //RPC: Completed
      //Audit Logout

       //Audit Login
       var x = DataContext.OtherTable.Any(t=>t.Id == 4);
       //RPC: Completed
      //Audit Logout

}
```

**Update**

sql profiler is showing the 'duration' of these logouts as a couple hundred milliseconds. Thats time my app is waiting right?

Comment: You also might want to change FirstOrDefault to SingleOrDefault here (assuming you ID is unique... you will always get one result). This will remove the "Top 1" from your SQL qeuery. Perhaps you gain some mseconds again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` executes a query since it needs to give you a result back, not a potential collection - same goes for `Any`.  When you create a DataContext it doesn't log in right away.  I can assure you, though this may look "bad", it's completely fine.

Comment: but sql profiler is showing the 'duration' of these logouts as a couple hundred milliseconds.  Thats time my app is waiting right?

Answer (score 1):

In Linq-2-sql Any() and .FirstOrDefault() called the way you are using them here are not deferred. When you call them they will cause execution to occur. So in this case they will fire immediately and that is what you also noticed in the profiler.

See also: [How to maintain LINQ deferred execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1308129/532498)

I think you are mixing deferred execution of queries on the one hand and updates on the other hand a bit.

Every time you call Submitchanges, all changes waiting to happen are submitted. Generally you need to do this only once and all changes are done in one transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The L2S datacontext does not persist connections which is why you see Login/Logout in the profiler. It does persist states, which is important for change tracking.

Here's a good article for L2S DataContext management: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management

Comment: If it doesn't persist connections, then how does it behave in a transaction scope?  The underlying code seems to prevent closing a connection when done, if a transaction scope is present; however, I'm noticing that after 10 or 15 minutes of being in a transaction scope and calling SubmitChanges over and over within that scope... eventually there's a sudden and seeming random "Audit Logout" encountered and the connection is closed, causing the transaction to fail.  The transaction timeout is like 6 hours, but this is failing in 10 to 15 minutes for no apparent reason.